# Bash extglob pattern with comma

Tags: bash, wildcards

Suppose `extglob` is turned on in Bash (I use 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0)) and we have a file with the name `list89988777,,,,,+--.txt`. I cannot get a `,` to work in extglob pattern with `[...]` unless I escape not just the comma but all that goes with it if the `,` is the first in a `[..]`, which does not make sense to me. Hence:

`ls *+([[:digit:]]|[\,\-\+]).txt` works, so does

`ls *+([[:digit:]]|[[:punct:]]|[-\,+]).txt` as well as

`ls *+([[:digit:]]|[[:punct:]]|[-+\,]).txt`

but

`ls *+([[:digit:]]|[\,-+]).txt` does not work.

Problem can be solved with `ls *+([[:digit:]]|[[:punct:]]|[-+]).txt`, which works, or for that matter with `ls *+([[:digit:]]|[[:punct:]]|[,-+]).txt` which also works. But why is escaping `,` and all the other chars in a `[...]` necessary if the first char is a `,`?

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. It is the `-` that creates the unintended pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to the user who answered the question in a comment (but then the comment vanished).

It is not the `,` but actually the `-` within `[...]` that causes the problem because it creates a range. Hence, escaping `,` is not necessary, we just need to make sure the `-` is first or last in the set.